# Rally software cardboard with only a iteration dropdown and defects cards

Tags: rally, defects

How do I create a cardboard in Rally Software that has just an iteration dropdown and a defect list. I have tried the examples on the dev site and they give me user stories and defects. I just need the defects.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example on this [page](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/card-board), you will need to change this line:

```
      types : ["Defect", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
```

to this

```
      types : ["Defect"],
```

-- Mark

Comment: Any idea on how to add a dropdown menu for the iteration. I tried the one on the example site and it showed no defects. Which I know I have. I also need to print them after they select the iteration.

Comment: Do you have defects assigned to iterations? Have you looked at your JavaScript debugger to see the web service response?

Answer (score 0):

actually, not sure that page has the example tied to iteration dropdown.  However, I went through this myself :)  Check this post out, and take the above advice on that code.  [Rally Custom Kanban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563972/rally-custom-kanban)

on that code, you will want to replace the 
a
b
c 
etc

with the names to your column headers, and also assign it the proper field to look at (code uses KanbanState field.