# Rally Custom Kanban

Tags: rally, kanban

I would like to only show stories/defects from the current iteration on a kanban type board to help with our process.

So I found this example out here on SO and added the QUERY line to filter out my iteration.  But now I am wanting this to come from the iterationdropdown box provided by rally.

I added it to the screen, and it shows ok, but how do I actually hook it up to my query?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Custom App</title>

    <!--Include SDK-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/sdk.js"></script>

    <!--App code-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Rally.onReady(function() {

            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',
                mappedToField:"State",
                mappedFromField:"KanbanState",

                fieldNameMap:{
                   a:"New",
                   b:"New",
                   c:"Defined",
                   d:"In-Progress",
                   e:"In-Progress",
                   f:"Completed",
                   g:"Completed",
                   h:"Accepted"
                },

                launch: function() {
                     this.add({
                        xtype:'rallyiterationcombobox',
                        itemId: 'iterationComboBox',
                    });

                    this.add({
                        xtype:'rallycardboard',
                        types: ["Defect", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
                        query: 'Iteration.Name contains "UB Sprint 29"',
                        attribute: this.mappedFromField,
                        listeners:{
                            beforecarddroppedsave:function(cardboard, card) {
                                //map the new state from on this card to the new state
                                var newState = this.fieldNameMap[card.record.get(this.mappedFromField)];
                                card.record.set(this.mappedToField, newState);
                            },
                            scope:this
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'My Custom App'
            });

        });

    </script>


    </head>
    <body class="myApp">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter by iteration you need to add a listener to the [iteration combobox](https://test7cluster.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.IterationComboBox-event-select) and have it create the board based upon the current selected iteration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My Kanban by Iteration

```
<!--Include SDK-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/sdk.js"></script>

<!--App code-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    Rally.onReady(function() {

        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
            mappedToField:"State",
            mappedFromField:"KanbanState",

            kanban:undefined,
            fieldNameMap:{
                a:"New",
                b:"New",
                c:"Defined",
                d:"In-Progress",
                e:"In-Progress",
                f:"Completed",
                g:"Completed",
                h:"Accepted"
            },

            launch: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype:'rallyiterationcombobox',
                    itemId: 'iterationComboBox',
                    listeners: {
                        select: this.createKanban,
                        ready: this.createKanban,
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
            },
            createKanban:function(combo, records) {
                if (this.kanban) {
                    this.kanban.destroy();
                }
                var filters = [];
                if (records.length) {
                    filters.push({
                        property: 'Iteration',
                        value: records[0].get("_ref")
                    });
                }
                this.kanban = this.add({
                    xtype:'rallycardboard',
                    types: ["Defect", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
                    attribute: this.mappedFromField,
                    listeners:{
                        beforecarddroppedsave:function(cardboard, card) {
                            //map the new state from on this card to the new state
                            var newState = this.fieldNameMap[card.record.get(this.mappedFromField)];
                            card.record.set(this.mappedToField, newState);
                        },
                        scope:this
                    },
                    storeConfig:{
                        filters:filters
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'My Kanban by Iteration'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I got this working :)  Appreciate you helping us all out.  When I get this all going though, I dont have the defects/tasks on the cards like the default kanban board does.  I looked around to find other CardConfigs that may have that, but only see the rallyartifcatcard, which doesnt show them either.  Is there a way to use the kanban card that rally uses to get that info as well?  thanks again

Comment: The cards you are looking at are for the SDK 1.0 boards. The next version of the AppSDK 2.0 should have some better card functionality. You may want to wait for us to finish releasing it if you do not want to reproduce it yourself.

Comment: I actually figured this out after a bit of digging :)  Thanks for the help !

Comment: I added this code as is to as a custom html app and only the iteration dropdown appears.